# Diffeomorphism Implies Equality of Dimensions

Tags: proof-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm trying to prove the following.

> If $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism from an $m$-dimensional (non-empty) manifold to an $n$-dimensional manifold, then $m=n$.

**My attempt**: Fix a point $p\in M$ and consider the differential $(Df)_{p}:T_{p}M\to T_{q}N$, where $q=f(p)$. If we choose local coordinates $\{x^{1},\ldots,x^{m}\}$ centered at $p$, then $$\left\lbrace\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\bigg|_{p},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{m}}\bigg|_{p}\right\rbrace$$ is a basis for the tangent space $T_{p}M$. Similarly, if we pick local coordinates $\{y^{1},\ldots, y^{n}\}$ centered at $q=f(p)$, then $$\left\lbrace\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{1}}\bigg|_{q},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{n}}\bigg|_{q}\right\rbrace$$ is a basis for $T_{q}N$. In particular, we have $\dim(M)=\dim(T_{p}M)=m$ and $\dim(N)=\dim(T_{q}N)=n$. Since $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism by assumption, the differential $(Df)_{p}:T_{p}M\to T_{q}N$ is an isomorphism. But isomorphic vector spaces must have the same dimension, so we may conclude that $m=n$.

**My concerns:** I think this okay, but it also seems too simple. Overall, does this proof work? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you can skip all the discussion of bases: A diffeomorphism is a smooth map with smooth inverse; applying this to $df_p$, we see that map is invertible, and we are done! In fact, that this is so simple might be considered one justification to spend time thinking about smooth manifolds and smooth maps (instead of continuous maps), where it is much, much harder to write a proof that manifolds of different dimension are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Looks good to me. Diffeomorphic invariance of dimension is much easier to show than homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for the verifications!

Comment: Why the non-empty? Sir_Math_Cat and @Shaun_the_Post